# Mat Select appears in the bottom of the page

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a problem while trying to show the list of values contained in a `<mat-select>`. I get all the list of options in the bottom of the page instead of showing them next to the arrow of the `<mat-select>`.

[image]

Comment: please provide us some code, makes it much easier to help :)

Comment: Hi Hana_CH, please include the relevant code. There isn't much anyone can do to help you with what you've provided.

Comment: you can also look up the material [link](https://material.angular.io/components/select/examples). There are some samples how to use `<mat-select>` properly.

Comment: Did you include a theme?

Comment: i copied the same code from the official page of angular material so i will give you the code :

Comment: this is the HTMl code : `<mat-form-field>
                <mat-select [(value)]="selected">
                  <mat-option>None</mat-option>
                  <mat-option value="option1">Ajouter un document</mat-option>
                  <mat-option value="option2">Supprimer le Dossier</mat-option>
                  <mat-option value="option3">Modifier le Dossier </mat-option>
                </mat-select>
              </mat-form-field> ` and i don't have code in the .TS file

Comment: this is the content of my app.module.ts imports section 
` imports: [
    DragDropDirectiveModule,
    HttpModule ,
    BrowserAnimationsModule ,
    MatFormFieldModule ,
    MatSelectModule
  ],`

Comment: Please don't use comments to clarify, [edit] your question instead. Comments may or may not be shown initially. They do appear in order of votes. You also cannot format code properly in comments. Make it easy to help you by putting everything in one place --- the question.

Answer (score 6):

Include a theme, e.g. by adding this line to your `styles.css`:

`@import "~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css";`

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to include any pre-built Angular themes and doing so might interfere with custom themes. You only need to include the mat-core() mixin from angular theming.

Add this to your `styles.scss`

```
@import "../node_modules/@angular/material/theming";
@include mat-core();
```

Answer (score 0):

Including angular theme will solve this issue to your styles.css
like the below one mention
@import "~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/deeppurple-amber.css";